# UIMenucontroller in Today Extension / widget

Tags: swift, today-extension, uimenucontroller

I have UICollectionView in my Today extension. I'm trying to display UIMenucontroller when user touches a cell. For this purpose I implement three functions:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    return action == #selector(copy(_:))
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {        

}
```

The functions are also called! But menu is not shown.

Afterwards I tried another approach:

[CopableLabel](https://gist.github.com/steve228uk/f2362684bca527ff4f54)

with the similar result: all the functions are called, but menu is not shown.

So, my question is are there some limitation for using UIMenucontroller in Today Extension / Widget ?